# Prev/next entry linking when using Transcribe

Tags: structure, transcribe, entry

I'm using Transcribe and Structure to build multi-lingual sites.

I have come across an issue using the Prev and Next entry tags. I want users to be able to go to the next/prev blog posts.

If I include the standard EE tags (below) it includes all entries, from both language sites. I need to just display the entries from the Transcribe language site you are on.

{exp:channel:next_entry channel="blog" transcribe="disable"}

Next entry: {title}

{/exp:channel:next_entry}

{exp:channel:prev_entry channel="blog" transcribe="disable"}

Previous entry: {title}

{/exp:channel:prev_entry}

Also clicking on a prev/next link that is to a post from another language just gives me an empty screen, which you would expect as the content is specific to the other language site.

Anyone any ideas on how I can work around this issue?

Cheers
Darren

Comment: Idid you try not to disable transcribe?

Comment: Sorry, yes 'd tried both and copied the wrong version to my question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

it should work according to the docs. have a look here: http://eeharbor.com/transcribe/faq

Does Transcribe work with the next_prev tag?
Yes, Transcribe does work with the next_entry and prev_entry tags in ExpressionEngine, please note, it requires you to use the parse="inward" parameter, Here is an example of how it works -

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="news" paginate="bottom" limit="1"dynamic="no" }
    <h1>{title}</h1>
{/exp:channel:entries}

{exp:channel:next_entry entry_id='{exp:transcribe:entry_ids channel="news"}' parse="inward"}
    <p>Next entry: <a href="{path='your/path'}">{title}</a></p>
{/exp:channel:next_entry}

{exp:channel:prev_entry entry_id='{exp:transcribe:entry_ids channel="news"}' parse="inward"}
    <p>Previous entry: <a href="{path='your/path'}">{title}</a></p>
{/exp:channel:prev_entry}
```

Comment: I searched the docs but didn't look in the FAQs...Doh. This solution fixes the issue.